# Openssh Connection does not work with AuthorizedKeysCommand

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I have added these lines on sshd_config

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /authorizedkeys/authorized-keys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ssh-keys

-rwxr-x--- 1 root ssh-keys 712 Dec 23 22:36 /authorizedkeys/authorized-keys 
-rwxr-x---  1 root ssh-keys  712 Dec 23 22:36 authorized-keys
```

ssh-keys user can excecute the file(/authorizedkeys/authorized-keys).
but I cannot ssh to server; ssh git@myserver.com

in auth.log I can see this line,

```
error: Unsafe AuthorizedKeysCommand: bad ownership or modes for directory /
```

if I give 770 permission to /authorizedkeys/authorized-keys file, I get following error,

```
error: Unsafe AuthorizedKeysCommand: bad ownership or modes for file /authorizedkeys/authorized-keys
```

I  tried using root as the AuthorizedKeysCommandUser and changed permission and owner of /authorizedkeys/authorized-keys file. it did not work too.

I am using OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 on ubuntu 14.04.

note:I can ssh fine with authorized_keys file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Unsafe AuthorizedKeysCommand: bad ownership or modes for directory /
```

It's complaining about ownership or permissions on the root directory. According to the source code the file, the directory containing the file, and all parent directories (including the root directory) have to be owned by root. The permissions on all of these files and directories have to be 0755 (deny write access to group and other).

My guess is that you have group write permission set on your root directory, or something like that.

Giving 0770 permissions to "/authorizedkeys/authorized-keys" also causes that file to fail the permissions check.

For completeness, this is the section of code which emits the directory error:

```
if (stat(buf, &st) < 0 ||
    (!platform_sys_dir_uid(st.st_uid) && st.st_uid != uid) ||
    (st.st_mode & 022) != 0) {
        snprintf(err, errlen,
            "bad ownership or modes for directory %s", buf);
        return -1;
}
```

It emits that error if:

1. The stat() call fails for a directory
2. The file doesn't belong to root ("uid" is 0 here)
3. The file's permissions include write-by-group or write-by-other.

Comment: problem was with my root folder(/) permission. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`authorized_keys` file should be `chmod 600` and the `.ssh` directory should be `chmod 700` .

Answer (score -7):

you need to give proper permission to the keys on the remote host:

```
[remote-host]$ chmod 755 ~/.ssh
```

`[remote-host]$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: I want get keys using AuthorizedKeysCommand instead of using authorized_keys file

Comment: The AuthorizedKeysCommand is read before the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  man sshd_config will provide more details.